# Could I use an IPS based TV to edit photos in a color-calibrated environment?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, monitors

Over the past weeks, I've been trying to get all of my color issues worked out. Getting closer, but I'm not there. I've calibrated my monitor with a friend's calibrator and that helped. I'm using the profiles provided by the local processor.

It's close. How close depends on the viewing angle.

So I'm thinking IPS monitor might be a good next step.

Googling around, I see that I could get an [32" IPS based TV for $400](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00391Z83G)

Given that IPS based 22/23" monitors run $250-$300, this seems like a lot more monitor for not much more money.

What are the faults in this logic?

Comment: If your question is more along the lines of "Could I use an IPS based TV to edit photos in a color-calibrated environment?" I'd recommend editing the title/question to reflect that.  As written it seems like some might quickly see it as off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

The technology is much the same. LCD TVs usually have tuner circuitry (you probably guessed that part) and audio -- and are usually much lower resolution than an equivalent (or smaller) monitor would be. Televisions are usually 1080p max resolution (which, if I recall correctly, is 1920 by 1080 pixels). Smaller sets are often only 720p -- that's 1280 by 720 active pixels. Sure, they're big and bright and have wide viewing angles, but if you have to spend twice the amount of time scrolling (or can see only a small fraction of what you'd see on a computer monitor at the same zoom level) you lose a lot of utility.

Comment: Also 1920x1080 at 32" looks much worse than 1920x1080 at 21" at normal monitor viewing distances.  You'd need to push that 32" monitor further away from your face or the pixels would get distracting.

Comment: Now, if you only need 1920x1080, and you have a very deep desk, it'd be better for your eyes to get the bigger monitor and keep it further away.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you probably can.  But you'll still need to calibrate it properly.

An LCD television is pretty much the same thing as a computer monitor these days.  Differences are:

- Dozens upon dozens of gimmicky features that do nothing but degrade image quality.  You'll need to turn off edge enhancement, dynamic contrast, black level adjustment, dynamic backlight intensity or other "Eco" options, etc.  Sometimes these gimmicks don't turn on when you are connecting a computer to them, but at least on my Samsung TV they do, and you still need to adjust them.
- TVs are frequently factory set with contrast, brightness and sharpness set way too high, and you typically need to *cut* these settings to get a properly calibrated display.  With a computer monitor, they're usually calibrated to sRGB out of the box, or have an easy preset allowing you to do this.

Remember that not all panels are equal, even among the same panel type (ie, IPS).  While it has a good viewing angle, my IPS-based TV at home changes its black level and hence the blacks changes slightly when you are slightly off centre axis.  This is typical of many IPS panels, but for example my 20" Dell Ultrasharp, also IPS, doesn't do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How does one know which IPS monitor to choose?

Comment: I don't have an easy answer for that, other than to read lots of reviews - which tend to be hard to google for amongst all the sites with cut-and-paste product descriptions from the manufacturer wanting to sell you one.  My home monitor is a Dell Ultrasharp 2209WA and it's great for the price.  Most of the larger widescreen Dell Ultrasharps are also good.  Some also like Apple Cinema displays but I've less experience with those.